# Get image from web by HTML tag

Tags: java, android, image

Let's say there is a website, and I want a specific image from it.
The URL of the image I want changes with every page, but the location in the code always stays the same and is findable under this tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<imgur link>"/>
```

What would be an efficient way to do this?

I was thinking about downloading the source code, looking for this specific part and downloading the image through the URL located in content="". But with my current knowledge of Java, I would probably end up doing that through regexes and weird loops. Really inefficient.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: JSOUP is for parsing html.

Comment: But extracting that url can be done with some simple strpos() and substring() coding. Good reason not to use yet another library.